# Migrate from chromium to chrome, preserving settings and profiles (given multiple profiles) in a time efficient way

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

How do I migrate from chromium to chrome preserving all the setting? I have multiple profiles in chromium, each with different startup-pages, bookmarks, credentials, etc, which should be migrated to chrome non-manually. I tried to copy the settings with the profile files manually, as indicated by chatgpt, but unfortunately, that corrupted the whole installation of  chrome, disabled it from even starting.

Comment: You probably did a mistake then. Google Chrome will work with the profiles from Chromium, provided they are placed in the right location (and have the correct linux permissions and ownership)

Comment: @vanadium do you believe it suffices to just add the profile directories from chromium to chrome? do you happen to know which paths these directories should be copied to?